# Why does my year display with a decimal place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a page displaying a list of invoices. I want a select box at the top of the screen where the user can choose the year, so the page will only display invoices from that year. I want to populate the select box with only the years where there are invoices in the database. It's almost working the way I want.

**invoices_controller.rb:**

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all.order("date_invoiced DESC")
  @years = Invoice.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_invoiced)")
end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<%= select_tag 'year_filter', options_for_select(@years) %>
```

The only problem is that my years are coming out displayed as `2014.0`, `2013.0`, etc. Why is there a decimal place, and how can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: What's the column type in your date_invoiced table?  Sorry, my Rails is rusty but it seems like you might be preserving it as a float or a double when you want an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of data type do you have for your year? A float?

If yes, you could fix it like following:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all.order("date_invoiced DESC")
  @years = Invoice.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_invoiced)")
  @years = @years.map(&:to_i)
end
```

Or something like following:

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.all.order("date_invoiced DESC")
  @years = Invoice.pluck(:date_invoiced).map{|x| x.year}.uniq.map(&:to_i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I went with: `@years = Invoice.pluck(:date_invoiced).map{|x| x.year}.uniq`. For some reason, doing it this way doesn't require the `to_i`, although I still don't understand why. By the way, the date_invoiced field is type date. I don't know whether the components of a date field are considered floats or not.